# show fancytree checkboxes only for leaf nodes

Tags: jquery, fancytree

Is it possible to parametrize the JQuery Fancytree (http://plugins.jquery.com/fancytree/) so it only shows checkboxes next to the leaf nodes?

EasyUI Tree provides such feature, for example: onlyLeafCheck
http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tree.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can globally enable checkboxes using tree's 'checkbox' option, and then hide them per node using the "hideCheckbox": true property.

Comment: I havent noticed the hideCheckbox property on the leaf level, thanks a lot!

Comment: 'hideCheckbox' node option was removed in v2.23.0: use checkbox: false